# Complex query: find all users who rated at least 2 common movies rated by u1

Tags: mysql, sql

So we have the following relational database for movie ratings:

```
  mysql> select * from ratings;
+-----+-----+------+
| uid | mid | rid  |
+-----+-----+------+
| u1  | m1  |    4 |
| u1  | m2  |    3 |
| u2  | m2  |    5 |
| u2  | m3  |    4 |
| u3  | m1  |    4 |
| u3  | m2  |    5 |
| u3  | m3  |    2 |
+-----+-----+------+
7 rows in set (0.03 sec)
```

So, we want to find all the users who have rated at least 2 common movies the movies which are rated by a specific user 'u1'. In other words, if user 'u1' has rated movies m1, m2, m3 we want the user ID of all others who have also rated at least 2 of movies m1, m2, m3.

so in this case, the answer should be u3, since u3 has rated m1, m2, m3 which includes 2 common movies with 'u1'. I tried the following statement:

```
mysql> SELECT * 
       FROM ratings 
       WHERE mid IN (SELECT mid FROM ratings WHERE uid='u1');


+-----+-----+------+
| uid | mid | rid  |
+-----+-----+------+
| u1  | m1  |    4 |
| u1  | m2  |    3 |
| u2  | m2  |    5 |
| u3  | m1  |    4 |
| u3  | m2  |    5 |
+-----+-----+------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

so, this gives me the all the ratings that are on common movies as with user u1. Now, how can I get only those that have at least 2 entries in common with u1?

Comment: This sounds like an assignment.  You should at least edit your question and include your attempt at answering the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT R.uid from ratings R
JOIN
(SELECT distinct mid  
 FROM ratings 
 WHERE uid='u1') T
ON R.mid = T.mid
group by R.uid
having count(R.mid) = 2;

+-----+
| uid |
+-----+
| u1  |
| u3  |
+-----+
2 rows in set (0.15 sec)
```

Comment: This assumes that the `(user_id,movie_id)` tuple is unique in `ratings`. That's a reasonable assumption, something we'd expect, but it's not been guaranteed. I expect this query will throw an "ambiguous column" error, But even if it doesn't, my personal preference is to qualify *all* column references with a table alias.

Comment: @spencer7593, thanks for the inputs, modified accordingly and will keep in mind next time.

Comment: I'm not sure on this answer... it would correctly identify the two users based on the fact that they had the same number of ratings, but I don't see how this enforces, because a sample user 1 (having rated A, B, C, and R) and user 2 (having rated A, B, C, R, T, and X) would both join (as user 2 had rated everything user 1 did, but not vice-versa)...

Comment: @Justin Bell, you are right, but OP didn't have a condition that both users should have rated the movies same ratings. i have join on move id so that only movies that are rated are matched not the ratings.

Answer (score 1):

A query of this form will return the specified result.

```
SELECT o.user_id 
  FROM ( SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT u.movie_id) AS cnt
           FROM ratings u
          WHERE u.user_id = '1234'
       ) c
 CROSS
  JOIN ( SELECT m.user_id
              , m.movie_id
           FROM ratings m
          WHERE m.user_id = '1234'
          GROUP
             BY m.user_id
              , m.movie_id
       ) n
  JOIN ratings o
    ON o.movie_id = n.movie_id
   AND o.user_id <> n.user_id 
 GROUP
    BY o.user_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT o.movie_id) = c.cnt
```

Inline view `c` returns a count of the movies rated by specified user.

Inline view `n` returns the distinct list of movie_id rated by specified user.

The join to `o` returns all rows from ratings for those same movies. The join predicate (in the ON clause) performs "matching" on values in the movie_id column, and excludes rows for the specified user.

The GROUP BY collapses the rows to distinct user_id.

The HAVING clause compares the "count" of the movies rated by specified user to the "count" of the number of those same movies rated by each other user, and eliminating rows for users that haven't rated *all* the movies rated by the specified user.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT userid 
FROM ratings 
WHERE movieid in (SELECT movie_id FROM ratings WHERE userid='1234')
```

Comment: suppose user 1234 watched 2 movies m1, m2, if user 2 watched only m1, then also this query gives user 2 , which is wrong